# can dynamodb query for data with a list contains object that match some attribute?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

can dynamodb query data for list contains object that match some attribute?

my data format:

```
  [{
     pk,
     sk,
     gsi1pk: 'USER',
     gsi1sk,
     list:[
         {
           id,
           type, // admin, moderator, user
           name,
         }
     ]
  }]
```

can we do something like this to find data with list contains type is 'admin'?

```
   await Ddb.query( {
    IndexName: 'GSI1',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'gsi1pk = :gsi1pk',
    FilterExpression: 'contains(list, :list)'
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':gsi1pk': 'USER',
      ':list': { type: 'admin'}
    },
  });
```

this does not work now :(